With network manager (nmcli), how do I drop and renew a dhcp lease from the command line?
In Fedora 40 etc., the old dhclient advice for dropping a DHCP lease no longer works. Instead, dhcp is handled by NetworkManager. The GUI for this works great if you have it installed; with nmcli it is less clear.
After giving a static lease to the machine on my DHCP server, how do I drop and renew the lease on the (e.g. Fedora >=40) client?
